# Does laravel have any parser?

Tags: php, laravel, parsing, html-parser

Is there any method or functionality to parse some html/text built in laravel like codeigniter?

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html

Comment: isn't blade fiting these needs ?

Comment: Actually I need something which will show some DB data in html formate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes "{{}}" is used for parsing your php data to laravel blades.
Like for example:
 In your controller you have parsed some value like:

```
  class UserController extends Controller{
    $something = "something";
    return view('someView',compact('something'));
  }
```

So in your html blade you can use:

```
<html>
  <head><title>{{$something}}</title></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Please check below link for more description:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views